# How to create ReplyKeyboardMarkup with CallbackData?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

So I've been building my bot with InlineKeyboardMarkup and CallbackData which worked great, but became unpleasant from user experience perspective as bot can send images which forces me to send new messages with keyboard or make user scroll up to choice section which both bad. So I need to switch to ReplyKeyboardMarkup now.

Old code example:

```
keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("some_button", callback_data="some_callback")]]
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
```

The problem with it is its buttons send replies in chat instead of using callback_data:

```
keyboard = [[KeyboardButton("some_button", callback_data="some_callback")]]
reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
```

sends `some_callback` into chat instead of sending it to callback. I know there is no callback_data parameter accepted in KeyboardButton class(besides **kwargs, which are not used there)

I have searched for solution to this issue and found no documentation or questions about CallbackData in ReplyMarkup in telegram-bot-api, which i use for my project.

I found this useful link documenting telegram buttons: https://core.telegram.org/api/bots/buttons, but it did not help me, since i have managed to find nothing like keyboardButtonCallback in telegram-bot-api.

At this point it looks to me like telegram api supports the feature, but it's not supported by the wrapper used, so I only see an option to request this feature at telegram-bot-api github or create a pull request with feature code myself.

So are there other solutions to the problem?

Comment: DId you find any solution to this? Were you able to get callback data from the KeyboardButton?

Comment: @TahaMalik nope, i gave up on the idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only [`InlineKeyboardMarkup`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup)/[`InlineKeyboardButton`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) supports `callback_data`. [`ReplyKeyboardMarkup`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup)/[`KeyboardButtons`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton) are simple shortcuts for sending a pre-defined text and do not support `callback_data`. This is design decision made by Telegram and no Bot API wrapper could lift this limitation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Although, if you're right, what is the [keyboardButtonCallback](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/keyboardButtonCallback) under the link i provided in question? It clearly has text and callback data and works with ReplyKeyboard

Comment: It's part of the Telegram API (also known as MTProto), not the Bot API.

Comment: does it mean i can use this API to create ReplyKeyboard with callbacks?

Comment: I would be surprised if bots could create `KeyboardButtons` with `callback_data` using MTProto directly. Note that the Bot API is just a thin layer around MTProto, which basically exposes the parts that bots can use. IISC the [`KeyboardButton`](https://core.telegram.org/type/KeyboardButton`) in MTProto just represents both of `InlineKeyboardButton` and `KeyboardButton`.